# Why it is bypassing return Redirect::to()?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

If `$id` does not match to `$sessionPackage['id']` it should execute

```
 return Redirect::to('/order/' . $id . '/details');
```

For some reason it does redirect to a page, however it does output "Test" as debugging, so it mean that if condition is working.

In the controller:

```
public function showDetails($id)
{


    if (!$this->checkPackage($id)) {
        return Redirect::to('/');
    }

    $data = SessionOrder::getPersonalDetails();

    return View::make("order.order-details")->withData($data);
}
```

checkPackage() function:

```
protected function checkPackage($id)
{

    $this->package = Packages::getPackage($id);

    if (!$this->package) {
        return false;
    }

    $sessionPackage = SessionOrder::getPackage();

    if (SessionOrder::hasPackage() && $sessionPackage['id'] != $id) {

        SessionOrder::clearPackageExceptPersonalDetails();

        SessionOrder::storePackage([
            'id' => $id
        ]);

        echo "Test";

        return Redirect::to('/order/' . $id . '/details');
    }

    return true;
}
```

Update: If package ID does not exist then it would redirect return `Redirect::to('/');` but if package ID does exist and it does not match to `$sessionPackage['id']` it should redirect to `Redirect::to('/order/' . $id . '/details');`

Comment: Instead of Redirect in your "checkPackage" method you should store your boolean returned and do the redirection by testing the boolean in the "showDetails" method

Comment: @KeizerBridge I understand but there are two type of redirection it need to work. If package ID does not exist then it would redirect return `Redirect::to('/');` but if package ID does exist and it does not match to `$sessionPackage['id']` it should redirect to `Redirect::to('/order/' . $id . '/details');`  How would you do that in boolean or something in "checkPackage" method?

Comment: Ok so in your "checkPackage" method, instead of returning a boolean,  return a string which is the url you want. In case the method is returning "true" check in your main method "if (($url = $this->checkPackage($id)) !== true) { return Redirect::to($url); }" here the $url value is the string containing the url

Answer (score 0):

Instead of the redirection, you need to return false, and do the redirection in an else-clausule in your showDetails method.

Comment: Could you expend your answer a bit more please with example. If I `return false` instead of the redirection but there are two type of redirection. If package ID does not exist then it would redirect `return Redirect::to('/');` but if  package ID does exist and it does not match to `$sessionPackage['id']` it should redirect to `Redirect::to('/order/' . $id . '/details');` I am not sure how would you return two type of false?

Comment: You can also return a numeric value / a enumerator of throw an exception. The point is just that you cannot execute the Redirect in a sub-method but it needs to be executed from your showDetails method.

Answer (score 0):

Laravel route doesn't support cascade routing. So you have to redirect in your showDetail funciton, not in the child funciton checkPackage().